# O que é Refresh Token

Tags: token

Eu já pesquisei muito sobre refresh token e ainda não consegui entender muito bem.
Alguém me pode explicar detalhadamente o que é refresh token e como funciona?

Comment: Só depende do lugar onde está aplicando. Isso não é um termo exato, é um termo genérico que varia conforme o cenário, api ou aplicação. Você pode [editar sua primeira postagem sobre isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/564801/70) e dar o contexto onde leu o termo, que a pergunta pode ser reavaliada e eventualmente reaberta pela a comunidade. Para evitar duplicação de orientações, o campo de comentarios foi desativado aqui, mas [na postagem linkada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/564801/70) o espaço pode ser utilizado.